# Is there a way in tkinter to have a scrolling menu?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a cipher app that can allow you to choose the rotation you will use to encode your text. Preferably instead of using a drop-down menu with 93 different options, I would want a small box with up/down buttons where you can scroll through the options.

EX: I would do something like this:

```
status = IntVar()
list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
scrollmenu = tk.ScrollMenu(root, options=list, variable=status, command=check_value())
```

And when I place it the widget appears like this:

[image: Ideal]

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: That's the `Spinbox` widget.

Comment: thank you! I could not find the name of something like that.

Comment: Note that `command=check_value()` would call `check_value` method immediately after that line was read if `ScrollMenu` was an actual widget.

Comment: Yeah, i whipped it up real quick without regard for correct code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in [Novel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2229945/novel)['s suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48469593/is-there-a-way-in-tkinter-to-have-a-scrolling-menu#comment83933019_48469593) `Spinbox` fits very well to what you describe. Here's an example:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except:
    import Tkinter as tk


def print_value():
    global var
    print(var.get())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    var = tk.StringVar()
    a_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    spinbox = tk.Spinbox(root, values=a_list, textvariable=var, command=print_value)
    spinbox.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Another example (with `IntVar`):

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except:
    import Tkinter as tk


def print_value():
    global var
    print(var.get())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    var = tk.IntVar()
    a_list = [1, 2, 3]
    spinbox = tk.Spinbox(root, values=a_list, textvariable=var, command=print_value)
    var.set(4)
    spinbox.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out yesterday and im using it well. Is there a way to directly change a value of the spinbox? EDIT: nvm i can just use insert, spinbox has that function

Comment: @SnivyDroid If used with `var` above you can directly select using `set` as in `var.set('b')`. Not sure if not.

Comment: Im using it with integers, I can set up intvar but what then?

Comment: @SnivyDroid Same thing. `var.set(2)`.

Comment: but what arg do i set it to bind an IntVar()?

Comment: @SnivyDroid Updated my answer.